# Expand Collapse row functionality in exporting Excel File by asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am creating an excel file by openxml and want to give expand collapse functionality in that file.

How could I achieve this

Comment: I want to do it by OpenXml

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use EPPLUS library from codeplex. you can download it from **[here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)**

I have used it but not for expand collapse functionality but see [**THIS EXAMPLE**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample) for expand collapse functionality.